# Running python program on HTML button press (raspberry pi)

Tags: php, python, html, csv

I'm fairly new to this so any help is much appreciated - thanks!

My setup is:

RPi GPIOs hooked up to a set of buttons
RPi running a python script which monitors the GPIO and writes the number of times each button is pressed to a csv file
A PHP file which writes the contents of the csv file to an HTML table so I can view the results in the web browser of a networked computer

What I want to be able to do is to have a "clear data" button on the webpage that will run a separate python script to zero the contents of the csv file.

I have absolutely no idea how to do this - web searches imply that it's possible using a variety of options (JS and ajax to name a few) but it would be nice if I could do this without having to use any more languages or software - I'm struggling a bit as it is!

Thanks for your help - please let me know if you want to view any of the code I'm using.

Comment: Well apparently you already know how to create dynamic web pages with PHP. Why don't you write a PHP script that runs the "clear data" program on the click of a button? Or, if you like, you can [learn how to make dynamic web stuff in Python](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html). In your case, there's no need for Javascript, AJAX or any of that.

Comment: Thanks for the link Carsten - I've spent the last few days playing with the python/web stuff and it's opened up a lot of doors! I've ended up using your PHP suggestion for now but I can see that being changed in the near future.